# Long documents - what is a good control for displaying it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to display very long text (~10 pages) on my web site. These will be read-only though (atleast at this point). I was wondering what would be best control to do it in terms of performance or overhead etc?

Comment: It need to be paged or a long blanket of text is OK?  You have it already formated?

Comment: Does not have to be paged. Formatting might be needed in future but not at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the long text is a User Agreement, it is usually displayed as a popup, with a TextArea with scrolling. In Firefox and Chrome, TextAreas can be resized... so it is a good option IMHO.

**EDIT:**

There is a jQuery plugin, to help you split long text with pages. [Here you can see it.](http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/pager/#examples)